# Scope leak between arrays inside and outside of function scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm calling a function inside of my script main

```
function func(a) {
var idx;
a=a.sort();  

for (idx = 0; idx < a.length + 1; idx += 1) {
    if (a.indexOf(idx) === -1) {
        return idx;
    }
}
return 0;
}

var array = [2,1,0];
var b = func(array);
console.log(array);
```

The function argument (a) is an array that is being passed to the func function.

When I try to access the array in the main body of the program after calling this function it's sorted.

Does node.js link the scope between the array passed to the 'func' function and the array that was passed to it?

After calling this code, array is sorted. Why is that?

This is even true if I declare a new variable, b inside the function scope.

```
function func(a) {
var idx, b;
b = a;  
b = b.sort();

for (idx = 0; idx < a.length + 1; idx += 1) {
    if (a.indexOf(idx) === -1) {
        return idx;
    }
}
return 0;
}

var array = [2,1,0];
var b = func(array);
console.log(array);
```

The above code has the same issue.

Comment: Hint: `b = a` doesn't copy the array. (If you still need help, here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/kjou77ey/)

Comment: Is there a JS best practice way to copy arrays and objects? Re-building the array into a new variable inside of the 'func' function element by element seems cumbersome, is that the only way?

Comment: Copying the the array with `Array.slice()` is the best one can get. You have to copy it anyway since arrays are passed by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a scope leak but a twofold reason for what is happening:

1. because [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) directly modifies the array it is applied on (while also returning it)
2. functions in JavaScript work with pass by reference for objects

For reason #1 look at this simple example:

```
var a = [3,4,1,2];
a; // [3, 4, 1, 2]
a.sort(); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
a; // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As you can see it returns the sorted array which is nothing more than the array itself that has been modified by the `sort`.

For reason #2 look at this simple example:

```
function foo(a) { a.push('hello'); }
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr; // [1, 2, 3, 4]
foo(arr); // undefined
arr; // [1, 2, 3, 4, "hello"]
```

So combining those two reasons you can see that you are passing a reference to the array into the function and then directly modifying it with a `sort`.

If you want to do the same thing without modifying the original array you could use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which returns a shallow copy of the original array.

```
var a = [3,4,1,2];
var arr = a.slice();
a; // [3, 4, 1, 2]
arr; // [3, 4, 1, 2]
arr.sort(); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr; // [1, 2, 3, 4]
a; // [3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers why I was seeing this behavior!